# Subset the same period of time for different years

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset, lubridate

I have some time data that includes several years (no consecutive), I want to select the same interval of time for each year. For example I use this code to select the period for one year, how can I make this more efficient and do the rest of the years?

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- as.POSIXct("2004-07-01")
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2004-09-30")
inter<-interval(date1,date2)
subdf<-df[df$time %within% inter,]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned `lubridate` package this would work for you:

```
subdf <- df[month(df$time) %in% c(7,8,9), ]
```